# Flutter pdf packe fullfill all the a4 format?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I am using flutter pdf plugin.This is my code:

```
pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
          pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
          build: (pw.Context contex) {
            return  pw.Image(image,fit:pw.BoxFit.fill);//pw.Container(


                //child:
                    //pw.Image(image,fit:pw.BoxFit.fill));
          }));
```

The problem is that I want to make pictures fulfill all pdf pages.

but it looks like this:

[image]

There are spaces around the edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used FullPage and it worked.

```
 pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
              pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
              build: (pw.Context contex) {
                return pw.FullPage(
                    ignoreMargins: true,
                    child: pw.Image(image,fit: pw.BoxFit.fill),
                  );
                //pw.Container(
    
    
                    //child:
                        //pw.Image(image,fit:pw.BoxFit.fill));
              }));
```